# Conditionally Filter Options for References in Sanity IO

Tags: javascript, sql, database, backend, sanity

I have 3 schema,

1. Menu
2. Section
3. Sub-Section

i want to conditionally filter the list of options provided based on the current object. Lets say i want to create a new sub-section which is under Pizza Menu so i will input Menu: Pizza (I created it before) and so section input should only accept and display all the available sections under pizza menu only.

Code:

subSection.js

```
export default {
    name: 'sub-section',
    title: 'Sub-Section',
    type: 'document',
    fields: [
        { name: 'title', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'description', type: 'string' },
        {
            name: 'menu',
            type: 'reference',
            to: [{ type: 'menu' }],
        },
        {
            name: 'section',
            type: 'reference',
            to: [{ type: 'section' }],
            options: {
                filter: 'menu == references($menu)', // this does not work
                filterParams: { menu: 'Neopolitan' }, // ^ ^ This is static, cannot reference current object
            },
        },
    ],
};
```

section.js

```
export default {
    name: 'section',
    title: 'Section',
    type: 'document',
    fields: [
        { name: 'title', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'description', type: 'string' },
        {
            name: 'menu',
            type: 'reference',
            to: [{ type: 'menu' }],
        },
    ],
};
```

menu.js

```
export default {
    title: 'Menu',
    name: 'menu',
    type: 'document',
    fields: [
        {
            title: 'Title',
            name: 'title',
            type: 'string',
        },
    ],
};
```